# python3 JSON parse

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
        [
        {
            "Match":"solo",
            "Region":"eu",
            "Season":"2017-pre1",
            "Stats":[
                {
                    "ValueDec":0.9,
                    "ValueInt":null,
                    "category":"Performance",
                    "displayValue":"0.90",
                    "field":"KillDeathRatio",
                    "label":"K/D Ratio",
                    "partition":null,
                    "percentile":65.0,
                    "rank":null,
                    "subLabel":null,
                    "value":"0.9"
                },
                {
                    "ValueDec":1328.12,
                    "ValueInt":null,
                    "category":"Skill Rating",
                    "displayValue":"1,328.12",
                    "field":"Rating",
                    "label":"Rating",
                    "partition":null,
                    "percentile":22.0,
                    "rank":29346,
                    "subLabel":null,
                    "value":"1328.12"
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как достать значение "rank" там где "category" == "Skill Rating"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
import json

In [25]: lst = json.loads(s)

In [26]: lst
Out[26]:
[{'Match': 'solo',
  'Region': 'eu',
  'Season': '2017-pre1',
  'Stats': [{'ValueDec': 0.9,
    'ValueInt': None,
    'category': 'Performance',
    'displayValue': '0.90',
    'field': 'KillDeathRatio',
    'label': 'K/D Ratio',
    'partition': None,
    'percentile': 65.0,
    'rank': None,
    'subLabel': None,
    'value': '0.9'},
   {'ValueDec': 1328.12,
    'ValueInt': None,
    'category': 'Skill Rating',
    'displayValue': '1,328.12',
    'field': 'Rating',
    'label': 'Rating',
    'partition': None,
    'percentile': 22.0,
    'rank': 29346,
    'subLabel': None,
    'value': '1328.12'}]}]

In [27]: [x['rank'] for x in lst[0]['Stats'] if 'category' in x and x['category'] == 'Skill Rating' and 'rank' in x]
Out[27]: [29346]

In [28]: [x['rank'] for x in lst[0]['Stats'] if 'category' in x and x['category'] == 'Skill Rating' and 'rank' in x][0]
Out[28]: 29346
```

Comment: А если словарей больше? У меня почему то выводится другое число

Comment: А нет, всё работает. Спасибо тогда за помощь )

Comment: @Liptonus, всегда пожалуйста :)